# How to define a template for abstract methods of a typescript class?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, typescript3.0

When we create an abstract class in TypeScript it's like:

```
export abstract class Test {
    abstract anAbstractMethod(): void;
    public aPublicMethod(): void {}
}
```

...And then when we extend some class with it:

```
export class TestSon extends Test {
    anAbstractMethod(): void {
        throw new error('Method not implemented!');
    };
}
```

This `throw new error('Method not implemented!');` is created to help us not to forget to implement it's code. I don not know if it is VSCode that does it or if it's a pre-defined TypeScript thing.

Does anyone know how to change this line to some other code. It would be very good if we could define a **template** for each abstract method, telling the next programmer what more or less should be coded into the method, instead of depending only of the comments...

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But... if you want pre-defined code, shouldn't you use the abstract class for that? The abstract class methods can be overridden or not, when needed.

```
abstract class Test {
    aMethod(): void {      
      console.log("not yet implemented")
    }
    anotherMethod(): void {      
      console.log("not yet implemented")
    }
}

class TestSon extends Test {
   anotherMethod(){
     console.log("this is implemented")
   }
}

let s = new TestSon()
s.aMethod()
s.anotherMethod()
```

Comment: By your example, the compiler will not require from user to implement the method, and that may lead to error.

Comment: That's why the `throw new Error()` is put there by the IDE. To remind the user to implement the method. How else would you force the user to implement the method? If you want default code, that's what the parent class is for.